# A/the in context

Tags: articles

A lot happened between the time we met and got on **a** bus.

A lot happened between the time we met and got on **the** bus.

Which is right grammatically? Using **the** or **a** here. We use both take a bus and take the bus, depending the significance the bus is to the story, which suggests that if the bus plays no important role in the story either **a** or **the** should be fine, right? So here, with the given sentence, either should be fine, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are fine. The one with "a bus" relates to an unspecified bus, perhaps suggesting the particular bus was not of interest. The other with "the bus" relates to a specific bus suggesting that that particular bus was of some interest to the rest of the discussion.

Either is fine. The choice depends on the rest of what is being said.